# Excel stops working when adding new row to the Table

Tags: forms, vba, excel, listbox

I don't know why but when I try to do this Excel Quits without saving anything:

1. On `Sheet1` I have 11 Rows x 6 cols formatted as Table. With 1st row as Table Header.
2. I assign `col A` as a `STU_ID` Named Range using Name Manager.
3. I have only a `listbox` on the Userform. And I give RowSource property as `=STU_ID` . I get the `col A` data on the list box.
4. Now when I go to `Sheet1` and try to add more data on next row of the table. Excel quits saying it has stopped working. Windows is checking for error and it restarts on a blank `Workbook`.

> Shouldn't Listbox be dynamic and get data from Name Manager as I add them on the sheet ?

I am using MS Excel Pro 13 on Win 10 64 bit.

Comment: Strange. Try using proper `Table` names instead of `Name manager's` `Named range`. E.g. `=Table1[HeaderOfMyColoumn]` (Use your table's name and the actual column name, obviously.)

Comment: okay let me try it will let you know soon

Comment: @vacip Same Results it restarted right when I try to add new data to the table

Comment: Wow! And it does die, I was surprised to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Strange right you got that problem too right ?

Comment: @vacip What I did eventually was I removed the table format and converted to range. Then it was okay. But then again the listbox wont be dynamic right ?

Comment: Let me try something. By the way, this seems to be a bug that was first seen in the 2010 version. Good to know Microsoft holds on to their bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Excel. As a workaround, use the `.List` property instead of the `.RowSource`.

Try something like this in the UserForm's code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ListBox1.List = Range("table1[abc]").Value
End Sub
```

This way it will be dynamic, and it will work.

If you need it to change while the userform is displayed, put a small code to the `Sheet change` event, that updates the list every time the sheet changes. (This is only necessary if your form is modal, and you want it to reflect the changes made in real-time.)